# python-for-android, Cython, C++, CythonRecipe: Operation only allowed in c++

Tags: c++, cython, buildozer, python-for-android

I have this setup.py for my Cython project:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name = 'phase-engine',
    version = '0.1',
    ext_modules = cythonize(["phase_engine.pyx"] + ['music-synthesizer-for-android/src/' + p for p in [
            'fm_core.cc', 'dx7note.cc', 'env.cc', 'exp2.cc', 'fm_core.cc', 'fm_op_kernel.cc', 'freqlut.cc', 'lfo.cc', 'log2.cc', 'patch.cc', 'pitchenv.cc', 'resofilter.cc', 'ringbuffer.cc', 'sawtooth.cc', 'sin.cc', 'synth_unit.cc'
        ]],
        include_path = ['music-synthesizer-for-android/src/'],
        language = 'c++',
    )
)
```

when I run buildozer, it gets angry about some Cython features only being available in C++ mode:

```
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.p_synth_unit
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

phase_engine.pyx:74:8: Operation only allowed in c++
```

from which I understand it's ignoring my setup.py and doing its own somehow. How do I give it all these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

`CythonRecipe` doesn't work well for Cython code that imports C/C++ code. Try `CompiledComponentsPythonRecipe`, or if you're having issues with `#include <ios>` or some other thing from the C++ STL, `CppCompiledComponentsPythonRecipe`:

```
from pythonforandroid.recipe import IncludedFilesBehaviour, CppCompiledComponentsPythonRecipe
import os
import sys

class MyRecipe(IncludedFilesBehaviour, CppCompiledComponentsPythonRecipe):
    version = 'stable'
    src_filename = "../../../phase-engine"
    name = 'phase-engine'

    depends = ['setuptools']

    call_hostpython_via_targetpython = False
    install_in_hostpython = True

    def get_recipe_env(self, arch):
        env = super().get_recipe_env(arch)
        env['LDFLAGS'] += ' -lc++_shared'
        return env

recipe = MyRecipe()
```

The dependency on `setuptools` is essential because of some weird stuff, otherwise you get an error `no module named setuptools`. The two other flags were also related to that error, the internet said they're relevant so I tried value combinations until one worked.

The `LDFLAGS` thing fixes an issue I had later (see [buildozer + Cython + C++ library: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol symbol-name referenced by module.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64755051/buildozer-cython-c-library-dlopen-failed-cannot-locate-symbol-symbol-nam)).